# Making a GDB debugging helper for the QUuid class

Tags: python, c++, debugging, gdb, uuid

I'm using the [`QUuid`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quuid.html) class in my project and for testing and debugging purposes it would be very nice to see the QUuid objects in human readable form instead of their low-level form.

For some reason, the people at Qt have not included a dump method for this type so I attempted to create one on my own, following [this](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-helpers.html) documentation and [this](http://plohrmann.blogspot.ch/2013/10/writing-debug-visualizers-for-gdb.html) guide.

I'm not familiar with Python so unfortunately, I could not get something running. Could someone help me create such a function that does nothing more than display the output of QUuid::toString() in the value column of Qt Creator?

Edit:
Mitko's solution worked perfectly. I expanded it a bit so the details can still be read if so desired:

```
from dumper import *
import gdb

def qdump__QUuid(d, value):
    this_ = d.makeExpression(value)
    finalValue = gdb.parse_and_eval("%s.toString()" % (this_))
    d.putStringValue(finalValue)
    d.putNumChild(4)
    if d.isExpanded():
        with Children(d):
            d.putSubItem("data1", value["data1"])
            d.putSubItem("data2", value["data2"])
            d.putSubItem("data3", value["data3"])
            d.putSubItem("data4", value["data4"])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following python script should do the job:

```
from dumper import *
import gdb

def qdump__QUuid(d, value):
    this = d.makeExpression(value)
    stringValue = gdb.parse_and_eval("%s.toString()" % this)

    d.putStringValue(stringValue)
    d.putNumChild(0)
```

The easiest way to use it with Qt Creator is to just paste these lines at the end of your `<Qt-Creator-Install-Dir>/share/qtcreator/debugger/personaltypes.py` file. In this case you can skip the first line, as it's already in the file.

As the `personaltypes.py` file is overwritten when you update Qt Creator you might want to put the script above in its own file. In that case you'll need to configure Qt Creator to use your file. You can do this by going to *Tools > Options... > Debugger > GDB > Extra Debugging Helpers > Browse* and selecting your file.

**Note:**

1. This script will only work inside Qt Creator, since we use its specific dumper (e.g. `putStringValue`).
2. We call `QUuid::toString()` which creates a `QString` object. I'm not sure exactly how gdb and python handle this, and if there is a need to clean this up in order to avoid leaking memory. It's probably not a big deal for debugging, but something to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I expanded on it a little bit (see OP).